# cannot log into chat

Tags: bug, chat, login

Can something be done to enable me to log into unix.stackexchange chat?

When I am logged into unix.stackexchange, I sometimes click on links to join chat, either within the comments of a posting, or in the formal chat room area.  But in each case, I am only able to view the requested chat room, and I get a message indicating that I need to be logged in before I can chat.  But I am already logged in at that point.

To clarify the problem, I try things like logging in again, logging in to stackexchange, etc.  But even after these steps, I still get the same message about not being able to join chat until I log in.

By contrast, I am allowed to engage in chat in other stackexchange sites of which I am a member.

NOTE: I am using CentOS 7 and Firefox.  However, I just tested it on Windows 7 using Internet Explorer 11, and the site did not allow me to log in to chat either.  In internet explorer, I tested it with both InPrivate and with normal browsing.  Also, this is a problem 100% of the time, so this is not a problem with server maintenance as suggested by a comment below.

Note: I am also not able to log into serverfault chat., but of course i can log in to stack overflow chat.
What gives?

Comment: Are you maybe selectively accepting cookies? If so, make sure you're not blocking any StackExchange ones.

Comment: Do you get any errors on [this page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/help)? You can try a [global logout](http://stackexchange.com/users/logout/global) and see if that helps at all

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Your `this page` does not recognize me either, even after I follow its prompts and login again via stack exchange, then visit your `this page` link again and find the same problem.  I will need to wait to try global logout until later.  I have lots of open things now that need to stay open.

Comment: @derobert I use the site incognito in firefox, which may have some impact on cookies.  But this does not cause stack overflow to keep me out of chat.  This problem is localized to unix.stackexchange, I think.

Comment: @CodeMed I believe [so] has its own chat server. Does it work on some other chat.SE, like say cooking or Ubuntu?

Comment: The test page shouldn't have required you to login, it just checks for common chat login problems

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249673/cant-login-to-sede

Comment: @muru I am not sure how that link is related.  This is a problem 100% of the time, so I don't see how it could be related to site maintenance.  I added a note to my OP indicating that I am using CentOS 7 and firefox.  Not sure if that combination contributes to the problem.

Comment: Is it fixed now? It looks like you were on chat last night

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No it is not fixed.  No I was not in unix.stackexchange chat last nite.  What happens is that someone asks to continue the discussion in chat, so the thread is placed in chat, but I CANNOT log into chat even though I am logged into unix.stackexchange, so I create a chat room at stack overflow and invite the person to have the conversation over there, where the chat server actually works.  If you can fix the problem here, I would be happy to have the conversations on this site instead of some other site. I have NEVER been able to log into unix.stackexchange chat.  I use CentOS 7.

Comment: Oh, I see. It wrongly shows you as active last night because a comment thread you were in got imported into chat. I'm not sure what the problem could be, but you tagged this [bug] so someone from stack exchange should notice it

Comment: I sometimes have trouble getting logged in properly to chat. I find it *usually* clears up after another one or two tries, and I tend to have better luck going to [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com/) and logging in manually there. Might be worth trying.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you.  I just tried that again, and then tried to enter the unix.stackexchange after clicking your link logged me into stackexchange.com, but still I cannot participate in unix.stackexchange chat.  This might be an issue of the site not being tested on a CentOS7/Firefox installation, but that is just a theory.

Comment: FWIW, I run Firefox on Debian 7.

Comment: I just revised the NOTE in my OP to report attempts to get it to work on Windows 7.  This is therefore not localized to CentOS or Firefox.

Comment: Quick update - CodeMed also cannot access a chat room off Security Stack Exchange

Comment: Curious, have you tried on a different network/ISP? Since you've tried two different operating systems, that'd seem like the next thing that could be wrong on your side. (Not sure where you are, but various ISPs have decided tampering with data in transit to e.g., insert ads or tracking is acceptable behvaior. Something like that could be going on and breaking something.)

Comment: Are you using "HTTPS everywhere"?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I do not use HTTPS.  I just click on links to get into chat, with the content of the hyperlink generated by the stackexchange site.  I added HTTPS right now, and it still will not let me log in.

Comment: @derobert I have not tried a different network or ISP.  I am using one of the major American internet providers.  A brand name ISP whose name most Americans have heard of.  If stackexchange does not support it, they are blocking a large percentage of potential chat users.  Remember that I can use stackoverflow chat successfully.

Comment: @CodeMed I suggest you should still test the function from a different network and/or ISP. This is not so likely to identify problems with your ISP (though it may) as it is to identify problems with your local network. If you have a cellular hotspot, and one of your problem devices has a WiFi interface, I'd suggest using that as an alternate test. Though I personally dislike the idea, you could also try via a local coffee shop's WiFi network.

Comment: If you have a virtualization platform available, I'd also suggest setting up a VM with a fully-default install of an OS and browser combination you're having trouble with. Make sure the virtual NIC is configured to "bridged mode" (VirtualBox) or similar. If you have problems with the VM in a fully-default configuration, then there's something between you and the web that's causing the issue. If the VM doesn't have problems in a default configuration, gradually configure the VM so that the OS & browser match your problem system - testing after each change - until it breaks.